# angularjs filters with an OR operation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have data array like this :

```
$scope.data = [{
  name: 'joseph',
  statarray: [{
    status: 'Online',
    status: 'Offline',
  }],
  active: 'yes'
},
{
  name: 'arnold',
  statarray: [{
    status: 'Offline'
  }],
  active: 'no'
},
{
  name: 'john',
  statarray: [{
    status: 'Online'
  }],
  active: 'yes'
}
```

];

```
    $scope.findObjectByKey = function(array, key, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i][key] === value) {
                return array[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
    $scope.Online =  function(array){
      var obj = $scope.findObjectByKey(array, 'status', 'Online');
      return obj;
    }
    $scope.Offline =  function(array){
      var obj = $scope.findObjectByKey(array, 'status', 'Offline');
      return obj;
    }
```

The functions $scope.Online and $scope.Offline sorts the data according to the status Online and Offline.

Here's my view :

I have these two checkboxes as filters :

```
<input ng-true-value='Online' ng-false-value='' type="checkbox" ng-model="online" type="checkbox">Online
 <input ng-true-value='Offline' ng-false-value='' type="checkbox" ng-model="offline" type="checkbox">Offline

<div ng-repeat="user in data|filter:online|filter:offline">
<p>{{user.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Currently when I click the checkbox corresponding to `Online` it displays the user `joseph` and `john` whose status is `Online` and when I click the checkbox corresponding to `Offline` it displays the users `joseph` and `arnold` whose status are `Offline`. This much is working perfectly. But when I click both the filter buttons it only displays `joseph` as `joseph` has both `Online` and `Offline` status. So an `AND` operation is being applied here. But I want an `OR` operation here. So when I click both the filter buttons I should get the output as `joseph`,`arnold` and `john` in the view. Any clue on how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

First, your `statarray` seems wrong, considering you declared one object with two properties with the same name, first we should move it to something like an array only containing the status strings ex. `['Online', 'Offline']`.

You are executing the filter function only using the latest filter selected.
You need to think in a different approach to aggregate your selected filters,
something like create an filter obj.

```
filter = {
  online: true,
  offline: false
}
```

and iterate over then to display your data

```
$scope.filterArray = function(array, key, value) {
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var shouldInclude = false;
        shouldInclude |= ($scope.filter.online && array[i].statarray.indexOf('Online') >= 0);
        shouldInclude |= ($scope.filter.offline && array[i].statarray.indexOf('Offline') >= 0);

        if (shouldInclude) {
            filtered.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
};
```

This is just one possible approach, if you are able to use ES6 functions this become even simpler.

Comment: actually it's some number's instead of Online Offline in my original data array. but since the code belongs to my employer so I cant copy paste it as it is here. That's why I used Online,Offline instead

Comment: Could you provide a more accurate example, hiding the real information? I didn't quite understand your data format.

Answer (score 0):

@ pravin navle-
Are you sure its working same as you described below code? Because when I tried to replicated same functionality it works only for Offline and not for Online as well as Both Checked.

Comment: please don't put comments or additional discussion as an Answer. it's really confusing